# Profile inheritance from main POM to Maven Invoker run

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles, maven-invoker-plugin

I have some profiles defined in my main POM, e.g.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>static-analysis</id>
        ...
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then I have some Maven Invoker tests and `invoker.properties` file:

```
invoker.goals = clean test
```

Is there any inheritance of profiles here? Will it be correct assumption that I can use `invoker.properties`as follows?

```
invoker.goals = clean test
invoker.profiles = static-analysis
```

I cannot find anything about profile inheritance in docs.

Comment: I don't think this is supported, but you could ask on the Maven developers' list.